# Create a simple quiz

Tags: webforms

I have a *videos* content type and I want users, who have watched this video, to answer some questions related to each single video.

How can I create a quiz for each single video node?
I tried the webform module and create a video block but there is a problem.
The  video will be shown in all forms and I can't insert video for next question.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module. I have some experience with it and it mighty suffice for your needs.

Or you can always create your own form with the well-documented [FormAPI](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7). You can define your own validation- and submithandlers. Very, véry cool features.
What you can do is [create a custom block](http://kahthong.com/2013/06/create-your-own-custom-drupal-block-programmatically), and fill it up with your own form.

Depending on your experience level (and time), you can one of above options...
Good luck!

Comment: how can I add a video to it ?

Comment: Hey Quiz module allow you to create a `Quiz Question` as a webform component. So you can just create a new webform, attach a video to it with a video field (just like you create a new content type) and attach `Quiz Questions` to is... Easy as pie :)

Comment: Sorry Michiel, I need your help again.  I want to add a swf file to an article page by using html code but i do not know why the video won’t play after adding the code to the body!!!

Comment: Hmm, this is a totally different question I'm afraid. You should ask a new question, place the link in your next comment and I'll help you from there :)